# Individual column filter not working in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables @version 1.10.11

All thing is work but **column Filter not working**. what is the issue?

is there external plug-in required or file?

Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#clist').dataTable({
        "ordering": true,
  "searching": false,
  "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  "dom": 'rt<"bottom"lip>',
  "columnDefs": [
   {
    "targets": [ 0 ],
    "visible": false,
   }, {
    "targets": [ 2 ],
    "orderable": false,
   }, {
    "targets": [ 3 ],
    "orderable": false,
   }, {
    "targets": [ 4 ],
    "orderable": false,
   }
        ]
    })
 .columnFilter({
  //sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
  aoColumns: [
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "select", values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']  },
    { type: "select", values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']  },
    null
  ]

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [`jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js`](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js) for columnFilter plugin, see [Downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/downloads) page.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7ckugec/1/) for code and demonstration.