# How to insert columnfilter in bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have bound my html table with datatable and the functionalities such as searching, paging and sorting are working fine. But when I tried to implement the  column filter using

```
$('#table1').DataTable().columnFilter();`
```

it doesn't work. It shows an error saying

> columnFilter is not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451387/individual-column-filter-not-working-in-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in a different way.

```
$('#demo-dt-basic thead tr th').each(function (i) {        
        var title = "Search "+$(this).text();

        $("<input class='form-control input-sm' type='text' placeholder='" + title + "'/>").appendTo($(this));
        table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
        });

} );
```